# What is the difference between mocking and monkey patching?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I work with python and I'm a bit new to testing. I often see tests replacing an external dependency with a local method like so:

```
import some_module

def get_file_data():
  return "here is the pretend file data"

some_module.get_file_data = get_file_data

# proceed to test
```

I see this referred to as "monkey patching" as in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch). I also see the word "mock" being used a lot alongside "monkey patching" or in what seem to be very similar scenarios.

Is there any difference between the two concepts?

Comment: This is a related answer https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4576#issuecomment-449864333

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) is replacing a function/method/class by another at runtime, for testing purpses, fixing a bug or otherwise changing behaviour.

The [unittest.mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) makes use of monkey patching to replace part of your software under test by mock objects. It provides functionality for writing clever unittests, such as:

- It keeps record of how mock objects are being called, so you can test
  the calling behaviour of your code with asserts.
- A handy decorator `patch()` for the actual monkey patching.
- You can make mock objects to return specific values (`return_value`), raise specific exceptions (`side_effect`).
- Mocking of 'magic methds' (e.g. __str__).

You can use mocking, for example, to replace network I/O (urllib, requests) in a client, so unittests work without depending on an external server.

Comment: So then are `monkey-patching` and `mock`ing essentially the same?

Comment: Sort of... there may be some confusion on the concept of a mock and the mock library. As mentioned, `monkey-patching` is the concept of switching some functionality out for another to facilitate testing. The `mock` is the thing that you `monkey-patch` with to replace the original functionality.  The `mock library` gives you an object you can use to `monkey-patch`. The `mock` object from the `mock library`  also gives you excellent features out of the box that helps you test that the mock behaves a certain way.

Comment: See also [@anthony-sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile)'s [post](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4576#issuecomment-449864333) to learn more about `monkeypatch` vs `mock` comparison.